# How to change default language in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9

I manage to create 2 language storeview. For example 1 is english and 1 is spanish. (for english the code is "english" and for spanish the code is "spanish"
I want to make everybody who enter my site go to my spanish language. 
I already change the sort order the spanish to 0, and english to 1. 
But whenever I open the site it still go to english not spanish.
How to make everyone to go to spanish when first open my website?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you need to check you website structure, from your comments it's like you already have 2 *store view* in a single website.

So if you want to be Spanish as your default language you need to go to *system > configuration > general - locate option* the you need to change your "current configuration scope" to "store view" and in click use default false from the combo of location options and search for Spanish - Spain ( you mast have already installed language package of Spanish from Spain to see Spanish).

Well, I hope this can help, let's know if you need feature help.

Best,
ALe.

Comment: Hi Ale,Thanks for your answer. I already do what you advise. But, what I mean is no matter the location is (for example: in USA) the language also spanish. Is that possible?

Comment: @dsc81 Yes it is. The location option I mention above is for language porpoise not a location for the store location. So if you want Spanish as a default anytime well then "go to scope configuration" set as website scope and change to Spanish (Spain). Let me know if this works.